# Failing to import an .eps file

Tags: import, image-processing

I have an .eps file which was created using GLE. There is nothing wrong with the file, GS View can read it correctly. However, when I use Mathematica to read it using

```
Import["dcl.eps"]
```

it returns `$Failed`. The particular .eps file can be found here [EPS file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/dgpa81e1nnmzi7z/dcl.eps)

I want to read this eps file so as to rasterize it, thus reducing its size. I'm using Mathematica v 9.0 under Win XP.

Any ideas why Mathematica cannot read this file?

Comment: Try Import["dcl.eps", "Binary"]

Comment: @RHall It's working but I want the true image not numbers in binary form. The whole purpose is to rasterize the image.

Comment: Just prefix the Import with Image@

Comment: @RHall Do you mean Image@Import["dcl.eps", "Binary"];

Comment: @Vaggellis_Z yes

Comment: @RHall Not working. Gives the following error message: mage::imgarray: The specified argument {37,33,80,83,45,65,100,111,98,101,45,51,46,48,32,69,80,83,70,45,51,46,48,13,10,37,37,67,114,101,97,116,111,114,58,32,106,112,101,103,50,112,115,32,86,49,46,57,32,98,<<1577498>>} should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers

Comment: I think you have to pass this file through a PostScript interpreter to see the image. It looks like a JPEG image, encoded so as to fit inside an EPS file. I don't think Mathematica interprets PostScript commands?

Comment: Mathematica supports only a small subset of the possible stuff that can be contained in an eps file.  First line of attack would be to go back to GLE and export as PNG or something. Failing that use ghostsript to convert to whatever, which you can easily script if you need to do it often.

Answer (score 14):

An EPS (Encapsulated PostScript) file contains executable PostScript code. Most applications don't attempt to interpret or run this code when 'importing' or 'placing' an EPS file. The EPS object is usually treated like any other JPG or PNG image, and sits there, looking pretty (if it has a preview). Only when the document is sent to a real (or virtual) printer is the PostScript code inside the file executed to produce graphical output.

However, unlike most applications, *Mathematica* executes the PostScript code when you import the file. To find out how much of the PostScript language *Mathematica* understands, it's possible to do some experiments using `ImportString` (which is easier than writing files). Here's a simple list of PostScript commands:

```
 ImportString["%!PS-Adobe
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 300 300
 newpath
 100 200 moveto
 200 250 lineto
 100 300 lineto
 closepath
 gsave 0.5 setgray fill
 grestore
 4 setlinewidth 0.75 setgray
 stroke
 /Times-Roman findfont 48 scalefont setfont
 1 .5 .1 0 setcmykcolor
 20 100 moveto
 (Hello!) show", "EPS"]
```

This sequence of graphic commands is interpreted correctly — even the top corner is clipped - my mistake there :).

[image: simple graphics commands]

Mathematica can also execute simple procedural code:

```
ImportString["%!PS-Adobe
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 200 100
 /csquare {
    newpath
    0 0 moveto
    0 1 rlineto
    1 0 rlineto
    0 -1 rlineto
    closepath
    setrgbcolor
    fill
 } def

 10 10 scale

 5 5 translate
 1 0 0 csquare

 1 0 translate
 0 1 0 csquare

 1 0 translate
 0 0 1 csquare
 ", "EPS"]
```

[image: procedural graphics]

And there are no problems with this sort of thing either:

```
ImportString["%!PS-Adobe
 %%BoundingBox: 0 200 600 300
 /pagewidth 350 def
 /doCircle { xpos ypos radius 0 360 arc stroke} def
 /increase-x { xpos radius add /xpos exch def} def
 /lineofcircles { /ypos exch def
      /radius exch def /xpos 50 def
      { xpos pagewidth le
      { doCircle increase-x}
      { exit } ifelse
      } loop
 } def
 30 250 lineofcircles
 1 .3 .4 setrgbcolor
 20 250 lineofcircles
 .2 .5 .2 setrgbcolor
 10 250 lineofcircles
 showpage
 ", "EPS"]
```

[image: more complex]

It's possible to run recursive code, such as this famous example:

```
ImportString["%!PS-Adobe
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 500 500
 % Sierpinski gasket By John Fouhy.
 /maxdepth 12 def
 /root3 1.7320508 def
 /triangle { newpath x y moveto a 0 rlineto 120 rotate a 0 rlineto 
240 rotate closepath stroke } def
 /rec {
   % usage: a x y depth rec
   % where a is the side length, (x,y) are the coords of the lower
   % left corner, and depth is the recursion depth
 /depth exch def
 /y exch def /x exch def /a exch def
 triangle
 depth maxdepth lt
 {
 /newa a 2 div def
 /newdepth depth 1 add def
 newa x y newdepth
 newa x a 4 div add y root3 a mul 4 div add newdepth
 newa x newa add y newdepth rec rec rec
 }
 if
 } def
 0 setlinewidth
 /length 450 def
 /xoff 30 def
 /yoff 30 def
 length xoff yoff 1 rec
 showpage", "EPS"]
```

[image: sierpinski gasket]

Admittedly, this is not a very useful feature (*Mathematica* programming is more fun than PostScript-stack-wrangling), but it's still cool.

### However...

It doesn't take long to find things that don't work, either visibly or which fail silently. Here's a simple example:

```
ImportString["%!PS-Adobe
 %%BoundingBox: 0 0 500 500
 newpath
 100 150 60 0 360 arc closepath stroke
 newpath
 200 250 60 0 180 arc closepath stroke
 newpath
 300 350 60 180 360 arc closepath stroke
 ", "EPS"]
```

[image: dodgy arcs]

and `arcn` (for drawing arcs in the opposite direction - important for making holes!) isn't available at all. *Mathematica* doesn't support every aspect of the language, although it's hard to find out what is supported and what isn't.

To address the question... *Mathematica* does support the `image` operator, for converting string data to a raster image. However, in the original file (dcl.eps),  line 17 refers to `currentfile`. A full PostScript interpreter would read the data from the input file (lines 35 to the end), but this operator isn't supported — so the data never gets read.

So the unanswered question is how to find out how much of the PostScript language is supported by *Mathematica*. Perhaps someone from Wolfram has the inside story.

Comment: Does your answer say that the only way to import .eps image is to rasterise it for instance to .ps? So .ps is only supported here as the rasterized image. I extended the thread here http://stackoverflow.com/q/37007587/54964